# Options for representing string input as an object

Tags: string, oop, artificial-intelligence

I am receiving as input a "map" represented by strings, where certain nodes of the map have significance (s). For example:

---s--

--s---

s---s-

s---s-

-----s

My question is, what reasonable options are there for representing this input as an object.
The only option that really comes to mind is:

(1) Each position translated to node with up,down,left,right pointers. The whole object contains a pointer to top right node.

This seems like just a graph representation specific to this problem.

Thanks for the help. 
Additionally, if there are common terms for this type of input, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends a lot on what you need to delegate to those objects. OOP is basically about asking objects to perform things in order to solve a given problem, so it is hard to tell without knowing what you need to accomplish.

The solution you mention can be a valid one, as can also be having a matrix (in this case of 6x5) where you store in each matrix cell an object representing the node (just as an example, I used both approaches once to model the [Conway's game of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life)). If you could give some more information on what you need to do with the object representation of your map then a better design can be discussed.

HTH